# jpegoptim save shell last run and check files or folders after this date

Tags: shell, jpegoptim

I have thousands of images which I optimize weekly by running it over a cronjob. My Problem is that it search also optimized images which lower the CPU. How could I save the last scan / optimization and began to optimize Files and Folders after this Date?

My Code

```
find . -name '*.jpg' | xargs jpegoptim --strip-all
find . -name '*.jpg' | xargs jpegoptim --all-progressive
chmod -R 777 *
```

Comment: `find | xargs` is actually unsafe unless using `-print0` on the `find` side and `-0` on the `xargs` side (unfortunately, these are both non-POSIX options, but fortunately, they're found in modern releases on both GNU and BSD sides of the world). `xargs` treats quotes and spaces in filenames as syntactic, so using the original code if your filenames aren't closely controlled could lead to, at minimum, content being missed.

Comment: BTW, `chmod 777` is **very** bad practice. Giving every user on your system -- which includes `nobody` -- write permission to a file means that software that the operating system is running as an untrusted user **because that software is considered to be handling potentially malicious data** can write to your content. `ssh` runs code early in the handshake process (before the remote system's credentials are authenticated) there, for instance. As a rule, `o+w` should *never* be done, and that's doubly true for `o+wx`.

Comment: (Now, granted, there's often other sandboxing in place -- `chroot` and the like -- but chroot on Linux is far easier to bypass than it should be -- if that weren't true, after all, there'd be no point to running untrusted components of sandboxed daemons as `nobody`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy thing to do is to touch a file to track the most recent processing time, and to tell `find` to limit itself to content newer than that file.

To keep the prior semantics, where we were running two separate passes, completing all invocations of `jpegoptim` in one mode before going on to the other:

```
#!/bin/bash

extra_args=( )
[[ -e last-scan ]] && extra_args=( -newer last-scan )

find . -name '*.jpg' "${extra_args[@]}" -exec jpegoptim --strip-all '{}' +
find . -name '*.jpg' "${extra_args[@]}" -exec jpegoptim --all-progressive '{}' + 
touch last-scan
```

---

As an alternative, consider:

```
#!/bin/bash

extra_args=( )
[[ -e last-scan ]] && extra_args=( -newer last-scan )

find . -name '*.jpg' "${extra_args[@]}" \
  -exec sh -c 'jpegoptim --strip-all "$@"; jpegoptim --all-progressive "$@"' _ '{}' +

touch last-scan
```

In this latter approach, we're doing only one `find` pass, and then passing each batch of files to a shell, which is responsible for running `jpegoptim` in each mode in turn for that batch.

---

Finally: *if* `jpegoptim` is safe for concurrent usage, you could do the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

extra_args=( )
[[ -e last-scan ]] && extra_args=( -newer last-scan )

find . -name '*.jpg' "${extra_args[@]}" \
  -exec jpegoptim --strip-all '{}' + \
  -exec jpegoptim --all-progressive '{}' + 
touch last-scan
```

Here, we have a single `find` pass directly starting both copies of `jpegoptim`; the risk here is that if `jpegoptim --strip-all` and `jpegoptim --all-progressive` can't safely operate on the same file at the same time, this may behave badly.

Comment: To search inside a Subfolder `find images/ -name '*.jpg'`

Comment: @karadayi, ...the word is "subdirectory"; "folder" is a Windowsism